# Postman 401 Unauthorized | Cannot GET

Tags: node.js, post, get, routes, postman

I'm doing a tutorial and cant get same result as in part https://youtu.be/qmNPpoVkY2Y?t=1238

I can POST via postman, but cannot GET.

Here's snapshot what I GET gives..

https://i.stack.imgur.com/i6Ezf.jpg

server/index.js

```
import express from 'express';
import dbConfig from './config/db';
import middlewareConfig from './config/middlewares';
import { MeetupRoutes } from './modules';

const app = express();

/**
*Database
*/
dbConfig();
/**
*Middlewares
*/
middlewareConfig(app);

app.use('/api', [MeetupRoutes]);

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.listen(PORT, err => {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }{
    console.log('App listen to port: ${PORT}');
  }
});
```

db.js

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

export default () => {
  mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
  mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/meetupME');
  mongoose.connection
    .once('open', () => console.log('Mongobd running'))
    .on('error', err => console.error(err))

};
```

middleware.js

```
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import morgan from 'morgan';

export default app => {
  app.use(bodyParser.json());
  app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false}));
  app.use(morgan('dev'));
};
```

meetups/controller.js

```
import Meetup from './model';

export const createMeetup = async (req,res) => {
  const { title, description } = req.body;
  const newMeetup = new Meetup({ title, description });

  try {
    return res.status(201).json({ meetup: await newMeetup.save() });
  } catch (e) {
    return res.status(e.status).json({ error: true, message: 'Error with Meetup' });
  }
}

export const getAllMeetups = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    return res.status(200).json({ meetups: await Meetup.find({} )});
  } catch (e) {
    return res.status(e.status).json({ error: true, message: 'Error with Meetup' });
}
}
```

meetup/index.js

```
import MeetupRoutes from './routes';

export { MeetupRoutes };
```

meetup/model.js

```
import mongoose, { Schema } from 'mongoose';

const MeetupSchema = new schema({
  title: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  description: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  }
});

export default mongoose.model('Meetup', MeetupSchema);
```

meetup/routers.js

```
import { Router } from 'express';
import * as MeetupController from './controller'

const routes = new Router();

routes.post('/meetups', MeetupController.createMeetup);
routes.get('/meetups', MeetupController.getAllMeetups);

export default routes;
```

I've tried to check spelling errors, but for some reason I cannot get this to work properly. Thank you!

Here is also request exported from Postman:

```
GET /api/meetups HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:3000
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
cache-control: no-cache
Postman-Token: e912d6ac-d9b6-465d-88e8-4aee65a906fa
title=title1description=This+is+a+descriptionundefined=undefined
```

Comment: The code looks correct to me.. Could you export the request (as a curl call, for example) from Postman? There is "Code" button there.

Comment: Exported and edited it to the bottom of the post! :)

Comment: Any luck yet? That's really weird. Only other thing I can suggest for now is simplify as much a possible, like narrow it down to just a router with inline handlers like `(req, res) => res.status(200).json('ok');`..

Answer (score 0):

Do you try to change **x-www-form-urlencoded** to **raw** on Postman?
Also choose type **application/json**

[image]

Comment: Yes, but no change.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Curl

```
curl -X GET your_usl?param=whatever
```

Comment: I get Unauthorized also

Comment: add header for add access_token in curl

`
curl  -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" "access_token: your_token"
`

Comment: curl -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" "access_token: http://localhost:3000/api/meetups"
curl: (3) Port number ended with ' '

Comment: In header if you don't have any access_token don't add in this if you make this public api then you don't have to put the access_token but I suggest you to secure your api always add the access_token with this. Then check !